Log request after taking out of connection pool in WebClient in Spring
I am using WebClient in Spring Boot to send requests to external services. I need to log request when request is added to the pool and it is actually taken out of the pool and sent to external service.
I am able to do this by using doOnRequest method of reactor netty's HTTP client, but my problem is I am not able to log the actual headers / request body in JSON format.
Here is my code -
This is how I am creating WebClient:
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
                .create(ConnectionProvider.create(connectionProviderName, maxConnections, true))
                .doOnRequest((req, conn) -> {
                    logger.info("HTTP Request Sent + " req);
                    // req.requestHeaders() does not give all the headers;
                });
return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build();

This is how I am sending request using same WebClient -
logger.info("Request prepared."); // Complete request is logged (header + request body)
String response = webClient.post()
                        .uri(uri)
                        .headers(h -> h.addAll(headers))
                        .body(Mono.just(myRequest), MyRequest.class)
                        .retrieve()
                        .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is4xxClientError(), response -> {
                            // return error
                        })
                        .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.is5xxServerError(), response -> {
                            // return error
                        })
                        .bodyToMono(String.class)
                        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(50000))
                        .block();

I want to print complete request with headers and request body on both logs. Suppose, if I set max connections as 5 in HTTP client while building WebClient and if I hit total 6 requests, I can actually see a time difference between request prepared log and HTTP request sent log which is expected and which is exactly I want. (Time difference is time taken for the request to wait in connection pool)
I am able to print complete request in request prepared log, however I want to print complete request on doOnRequest method also.
I know if I enable wiretap, requests will be logged. But I have a custom logger which logs some specific details and in JSON format.
Is there anyway I can log request when request is taken out of pool with headers and request body?

If you want to log in json format that is what you should build. a toString isn't going to give you the needed results (yes that is what is being invoked if you concat an object to a String).

why not just use a filter? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-filter.html
